# List returns null model when passing from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My model is always be null when sent back to controller. I tried many way to solve it but nothing worked. I check the network tap after submit the button and see all values are correct but in controller the model still be null.

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OTWebApplication.Models
{
    public class AP_UserForm
    {
        public String UFID { get; set; }
        public String UF_YID { get; set; }
        public String UF_FormID { get; set;}
        public String UF_FormName { get; set; }
        public String UF_EvaID { get; set; } // คนประเมิน
        public String UF_EvaName { get; set; }
        public String UF_RootID { get; set; } // พนักงาน
        public String UF_RootName { get; set; }
        public String UF_Available { get; set; } //ให้ประเมิน หรือไม่ต้องประเมินพนักงานคนนี้ 
        public String UF_STID { get; set; } // สถานะใบประเมิน
    }

    public class AP_UserFormL
    {
        public List<AP_UserForm> AP_UserForms { get; set; }

        public AP_UserFormL()
        {
            AP_UserForms = new List<AP_UserForm>();
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
@model OTWebApplication.Models.AP_UserFormL
<form asp-action="ManageAP_usershow" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EmployeeID</th>
                <th>EmployeeName</th>
                <th>EvaluatorID</th>
                <th>FormName</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AP_UserForms.Count(); i++)
                {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UFID" class="form-control" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_YID" class="form-control" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_STID" class="form-control" />
                                <input asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_RootID" class="form-control" />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_RootName" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_EvaID" class="form-control">
                                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ARoot)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item.ARoot_ID">@item.ARoot_Name</option>
                                    }
                                    <option value="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_EvaID">@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_EvaName</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_FormID" class="form-control">
                                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Form)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item.FormID">@item.FormName</option>
                                    }
                                    <option value="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_FormID">@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_FormName</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForms[i].UF_Available" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="0">ไม่ต้องประเมิน</option>
                                    <option value="1">ประเมินปกติ</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button input type="submit"value="Edit">Update</button>
</Form>
```

Here is the controller, for showing data, everything works well, but for `Post` method, it always gets null for its parameter:

```
public IActionResult ManageAP_usershow(String id)  
{
    AP_UserFormL ShowAPList = ManageAP_usershowList(id);
    ViewData["ARoot"] = GetARoot();
    ViewData["Form"] = GetForm();
    return View(ShowAPList);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ManageAP_usershow([FromBody] AP_UserFormL model)
{
    foreach(var item in model.AP_UserForms)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("pass");
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ManageAP", "Appraisal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `[FromBody]` tag from the parameter in your post method. The `[FromBody]` tag indicates to get the values from the request body in expected content type `application/json`, but you're sending form data. Try instead `[FromForm]`, which expects content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
[FromQuery] - Gets values from the query string.
[FromRoute] - Gets values from route data.
[FromForm] - Gets values from posted form fields.
[FromBody] - Gets values from the request body.
[FromHeader] - Gets values from HTTP headers.
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed already but it still passing null model :(.

Comment: I tried modelState.isValid and it sent back that the model is error. Can you advise what I need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it this way?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ManageAP_usershow([FromBody] AP_UserForm model)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried already but still null :(

Thank you for helping. Do you have another way ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause already.
View sent list to Controller but because of the exceed of data.

> fail: OTWebApplication.Controllers.AppraisalController[0]
> ModelState error for : Failed to read the request form. Form value count limit 1024 exceeded.

and I do put this code on the **program.cs**

```
fail: OTWebApplication.Controllers.AppraisalController[0]
      ModelState error for : Failed to read the request form. Form value count limit 1024 exceeded.
```

now the controller can received the list already.
Appreciate all help. Thank you!